# SVN/ PySVN: Get path to last changed files

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

TL;DR Having an url to a SVN repo, how can I substract all the paths to the files that have been changed since a given revision number?

Long Story: I have a script that downloads some files from a SVN repo. It does so every 'n' hours.
But if I only changed one file, I do not need to re-download everything again, just that file. 
I've tried to check every file with PySVN to see if the revision number has changed, but it takes too long (for a folder with 6 files it takes ~20 seconds).
Is there any way I can improve this?

I am working in Python with PySVN. I've seen that pysvn.Client.log has  'changed_paths' attribute, but it seems that I do not know how to handle it :\
This program runs on both Linux and windows, so the solution must be cross-platform (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pysvn.Client().log() to find all the changes. For example:

```
all_logs = pysvn.Client().log( path,
   revision_start=pysvn.Revision( opt_revision_kind.head ),
   revision_end=pysvn.Revision( opt_revision_kind.number, last_revision ),
   discover_changed_paths=True )
```

This will always return atleast one log for the last_revision. You can either just ignore that or use last_revision+1 and catch the error from svn about missing revision.

pysvn.Client().update() will figure of the smartest way to get changes into your working copy.

Remember that you can checkout only a part of the whole repo by a combination of selecting which folder to start with and then using the depth feature to only get the folder you need. For example:

```
pysvn.Client().checkout( URL, path, depth=pysvn.depth.files )
```

Then you only need to use update() to keep the files updated.

Barry Scott author of pysvn.

Comment: Could you explain what are `pysvn.Revision( opt_revision_kind.head )` and `pysvn.Revision( opt_revision_kind.number, last_revision)` ? I also discovered pysvn.Client().diff, but I do not know what `peg_revision` is and/or how to use it.

Comment: @hadarS Please read the documentation. You should find all you need in the ref docs. http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html Also you can raise bug reports against pysvn to have the docs improved on pysvn.tigris.org if there is missing/incomplete documentation.

Comment: @hadarS Oh and if there are SVN terms that you do not recognise it is where looking in the SVN manual for a definition. pysvn is a wrapper around svn and reflects svn's terminology.

Answer (score 1):

The summary makes me think that your are trying to re-invent a bicycle. Just checkout and update a working copy instead of exporting the data. That's the task of working copy and the update command.

BTW, I'd better use the [official SWIG Python bindings](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/python/) instead of PySVN.